# Why isn't my print statement showing up after my if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python, and decided to dab with a 'What year is it' thing. Here's what I have:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
currentyear = now.year

userinput = input("What year is it? ")

if userinput == currentyear:
 print ("Correct! The year is %s") % (currentyear)
```

However, it never prints out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if int(userinput) == currentyear` or `if userinput == str(currentyear)`.

Comment: int(userinput) seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, Python 3 does not implicitly evaluate input. Using a call to int() will fix the issue.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
currentyear = now.year

userinput = input("What year is it? ")

if int(userinput) == currentyear
    print ("Correct! The year is %s") % (currentyear)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the tag, and I wasn't aware of the issue as I mostly use 2.7.